# Copy pointers from one vector to another; the adress pointed to changes?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a vector of pointers to int. I like to copy those pointers to another vector. However, the addresses will not be the same. Why is that, how must I use *, &, const and auto in this case? Please note, this is not a question regarding smart pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int*> v;
    v.emplace_back(new int(5));
    v.emplace_back(new int(20));

    //copy all pointers to g; g shall have pointers to the int's in v
    vector<int*> g;
    for(const auto& i : v)
        g.emplace_back(i);

    //print all addresses
    for(int i(0); i<2; ++i)
        cout<<"&v"<<i<<"="<<&(v.at(i))<<"   &g"<<i<<"="<<&(g.at(i))<<endl; //will not print the same address

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
&v0=0x7bb070   &g0=0x7bb090
&v1=0x7bb078   &g1=0x7bb098
```

Edit:
After change the cout line to:

```
cout<<"&v"<<i<<"="<<&*(v.at(i))<<"   &g"<<i<<"="<<&*(g.at(i))<<endl; //will not print the same address
```

The output looks better :D, thank you:

```
&v0=0x2203010   &g0=0x2203010
&v1=0x2203050   &g1=0x2203050
```

Comment: You are printing the addresses of pointers. Why do you care what the addresses of the objects stored internally in a vector are?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think you might be printing the address of the pointer not the address the pointer points to.

Comment: What do you mean with "the addresses will not be the same" ?

Comment: ... after studying your code I understood that you mean "the addresses are not the same, when I expected them to be the same"

Comment: Just write `cout<<"v"<<i<<"="<<(v.at(i))<<"   g"<<i<<"="<<(g.at(i))<<endl;`

Comment: are you looking at the address of the pointers pointer?

Comment: `&*(v.at(i))` is lovely obfuscated :) just write `v.at(i)`

Comment: Thank you  juanchopanza, I made an edit.

Comment: tobi303: it's not about the value of the i-th element. It is about where a pointer points to.

Comment: @dani The value of a pointer (your i-th element) *is* where it points to. If `p` is a pointer, `&*p == p`.

Comment: You're looking at the _addresses of the elements_ so of course they're different in a different vector. They are different elements. If you want to look at  the pointers stored in the vector (not the address of those pointers) then stop using `&`

Comment: think of deallocating memory later on via delete because if you leave the scope of the vector without deallocating, you have a memory leak

Comment: _"I have a vector of pointers to int"_ Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the addresses of the pointers. Instead you want to see the values of the pointers. Instead do

```
 cout<<"v"<<i<<"="<<(v.at(i))<<"   g"<<i<<"="<<(g.at(i))<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

This comment is totally wrong:

> ```
> //copy all pointers to g; g shall have pointers to the int's in v
> ```

There aren't any ints in `v`, there are only pointers to ints!

So `g` doesn't have pointers to the ints in `v` it has *the same pointers* as `v`

Then when you print the values out you use `&(v.at(i))` which is wrong. For a start you could just write `&v.at(i)` without the useless parentheses, but more importantly you're not printing the pointers that you stored, you are printing their addresses.

To print the pointers you stored just use `v.at(i)` which will give the same values for both vectors, because you copied the values from one to the other.

`&*(v.at(i))` is just silly, and completely redundant. It's the same as `v.at(i)`